# How to get the same php multidimensional array with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

in my form I use jQuery to make an Ajax/Php request. This form send a multidimensional array to a php file, but I get an empty response.

The multidimensional array is created by getting values from a table. If I manually add the multidimensional array in the php file, I get the right value (so the logic of the php is correct).

This is the multidimensional array manually added to the php file

```
<?php    $ajaxArray = array( 
                                    0 => array(from => "01/01/2010",
                                               to => "01/01/2011",
                                               type => "Credit",
                                               amount => 10000.00
                                                ),
                                    1 => array( from => "01/01/2011",
                                                to => "01/01/2012",
                                                type => "Debit",
                                                amount => 200.00),
                                    2 => array( from => "01/01/2012",
                                                to => "01/01/2013",
                                                type => "Debit",
                                                amount => 100.00),
                                    3 => array( from => "01/01/2013",
                                                to => "23/04/2014",
                                                type => "Debit",
                                                amount => 100.00)
            );
    ?>
```

How to obtain the same thing with jQuery? See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6q8cS/8/ , it seems that the ajaxArray obtained here is the same as the one manually inserted in the php file, and I can't understand why I get an empty response.

*EDIT

This is how I send with jQuery the array to the server:

```
var ajaxArray = $( "#preview tbody tr" ).map( function(){
    var tds = $(this).find( "td" ); 
    return {
        from: tds.eq(0).html(),
        to: $(this).next().find("td:eq(0)").html() || lastDate,
        type: tds.eq(1).html(), 
        amount: tds.eq(2).html()

    };
} ).get(); 

                    var ajaxData = { ajaxArray: JSON.stringify(ajaxArray) };        
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '../form-response.php',
                        data: ajaxData,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (data) {
                                console.log(data);
                                $.each(data, function(index, element){

                    //...do something...
                                });
                        }
                    });
                });
```

This is how I get the array in the php file:

```
<?php
$ajaxArray = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['ajaxArray'])); 
?>
```

Comment: And how do you send this 'javascript' array to server side script? I'm not sure to understand your issue

Comment: Yep, please include your javascript code

Comment: You are right, sorry. Code Added

Comment: Try putting a `console.log(ajaxData)` before the ajax request, and have a look at to see if it's correct. Also, the dataType parameter is the type of data you expect the response to be, just in case you're not expecting to receive JSON.

Comment: This is what i get in the console log: Object {ajaxArray: "[{"da":"01/01/2010","a":"01/01/2011","movimento":"A","importo":"10000.00"},{"da":"01/01/2011","a":"01/01/2012","movimento":"D","importo":"200.00"},{"da":"01/01/2012","a":"01/01/2013","movimento":"D","importo":"100.00"},{"da":"01/01/2013","a":"23/04/2014","movimento":"D","importo":"100.00"}]"}  ....it seems to be right, consider that in italian da=from, a=to, movimento=type, importo=amount :)